# Перенаправление с http на https через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Ситуация следующая, подключил я ssl сертификат и настроил перенаправление с http на https, но возникала одна проблема имена с длинными путями перенапраляются не корректно. Т.е. путь вида site.ru/url1/url2/ работает как нужно, а вот путь site.ru/url1/url2/url3/ перенаправляет на https://site.ru/url1/url2/. Может кто подскажет в чем проблема?

Перенаправление работает следующим образом:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: У вас точно ссылки точно такие же, как в примере? Кэш браузера чистить пробовали?

Comment: Ссылки не прям идентичные, но если перейти по ссылке как в примере, то произойдет такая же ситуация

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой конфиг:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Не помогло, ситуация аналогичная

Comment: Проверьте такой код, должен работать

Comment: Аналогичная ситуация

Comment: У Вас точно 1 файл .htaccess? Что у вас в virtualhosts прописано по поводу этого сайта

Comment: Файл .htaccess один, virtualhosts должен быть стандартным туда я не лазил, залил сайт и на этом все. Интересно, что в целом перенаправление работает, но обрезает адреса выше второго уровня вложенности.

Comment: При этом если просто зайти по адресу с https то все работает, такая ситуация только при перенаправление

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в CMS. Она при редиректе не правильно перенаправляла

Comment: На ответ не тянет.